R – Model specification for TWO TIME variables AND PAIRED design in repeated measures generalised linear mixed model (GLMM) (in lme4 package)?
This question has already been suggested to be reposted here from stackoverflow.
I have a dataset similar to below:
Fixed effects of interest

Hour (4-level factor)
Response (continuous)
Treatment (2-level factor)

Random effects to control for

Day (10-level factor)
Location_pair (3-level factor (A, B , C))
Sensor (10-level factor (All unique))

So, the sample design is balanced:
3 locations x each location split by 2 treatment groups x 10 sensors = 60  sensors.

Ideally, I would like to specify a GLMM using the 'lme4' R package to test the fixed effects of treatment, hour, and their 2-way interaction, whilst controlling for the repeated measurements of sensors within their paired locations over days. I'm not interested in the effect of day.
Specifying GLMMs with repeated measures with one time variable seems relatively common e.g.

Crawley, M.J., 2013. The R book 2nd Edn. Page 695
GLMM FAQ (bbolker.github.io)
time series - R - Model specification for
repeated measures GLMM (lme4) - Stack Overflow

However, I cannot find specification for the aim above with two time variables, I'm sceptical about chatgpt's solution (https://chatgpt.com/share/104c1799-bcb8-4254-8558-3c23eba4fd81), and I've had limited success experimenting with different lme4 model structures. In the footnotes, I've provided simulated data, the model structures tested so far, and how I've assessed them.

Any advice on a reliable lme4 GLMM model structure would be greatly appreciated!
Alternatively, whether the aim of a repeated measures GLMM with two time variables is too complicated to specify reliably?
Whether better to only use a single hour/average of hours and drop that variable?
Whether a time series analysis in another package would be better than GLMM here?
Thanks in advance for any advice!

Footnotes:
Best performing structure so far:

Response ~ Treatment * Hour + (Hour | Location_pair / Sensor / Day )

Other converging structures:

Response ~ Treatment * Hour + (Hour | Day / Location_pair / Sensor )
Response ~ Treatment * Hour + (1 | Location_pair / Sensor / Day) +  (Hour | Location_pair)
Response ~ Treatment * Hour + (Hour | Location_pair / Sensor)

Didn’t converge:

Response ~ Hour * Treatment +(1| Location_pair / Sensor /Day) + (Hour | Location_pair / Sensor), data = data) - structure recommended by chatgpt
Response ~ Treatment * Hour + (Hour | Location_pair) + (Day | Location_pair)
Response ~ Treatment * Hour + (Day | Location_pair / Sensor)
Response ~ Treatment * Hour + (concatenated_DayHour | Location_pair / Sensor)   - tried different methods of collapsing day and hour into single variable, none worked

library(tidyverse); library(lme4)


mydata <- data.frame(Hour = as.factor(rep(rep(rep(c(1:4), 10),3),2)),
                     Day = as.factor(rep(rep(rep(c(1:10), each=4),3),2)),
                     Location_Pair = as.factor(rep(rep(c("A","B","C"), each= 40),2)),
                     Treatment = as.factor(rep(c("T","C"), each= 120)))
mydata <- purrr::map_dfr(seq_len(10), ~mydata)
mydata<- mydata %>% mutate(Sensor= as.factor(rep(1:10, each= 240)),
                           Response= as.numeric(rnorm(2400)))

str(mydata)
mydata_ncheck1 <- mydata %>% group_by(Hour, Day, Location_Pair, Treatment, Sensor) %>% dplyr::summarise(n= n()); view(mydata_ncheck)
mydata_ncheck2 <- mydata %>% group_by(Hour, Location_Pair, Treatment, Sensor) %>% dplyr::summarise(n= n()); view(mydata_ncheck2)
mydata_ncheck3 <- mydata %>% group_by(Location_Pair, Treatment, Sensor) %>% dplyr::summarise(n= n()); view(mydata_ncheck3)

  
  diagnostic_plots <- function(globalmodel, df, res_var, df_n){
    sresid <- resid(globalmodel, type="pearson")
    fits<-fitted(globalmodel)
    infl_model <- influence(globalmodel,obs=T)
    cd_model <- cooks.distance(infl_model)
    cd_thres <- 4/df_n
    devresid<-resid(globalmodel, type = "deviance")
    
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    hist(sresid) 
    qqnorm(sresid)
    qqline(sresid, col="red")
    plot(sresid~fits) 
    plot(cd_model)
    abline(h=cd_thres, col="blue")
    mfrow=c(1,1)
    
    cat("top left: data distribution
    top right: sresid_hist - bell shaped = normal dist
    bottom left: sreisd_fitted - random scatter = homogenous variance
    bottom left: as few outliers below cooks dist threshold (4/n) as possible
    NOTE!: Also consider plotting plot(sresid~df$variable_not_already_in_model) 
    - pattern = consider including")
  }

  

  model<- lmer(Response ~ Treatment * Hour + (Hour | Location_Pair / Sensor / Day ), data= mydata) # inset model here e.g. above
  
  drop1(model, test = "Chisq") %>% as.data.frame() 
  summary(model) 
  AIC(model)
  r.squaredGLMM(model)
  diagnostic_plots(globalmodel= model, df= data, res_var= Response, df_n= 2400)  # if too slow, avoid function and use below


  sresid <- resid(model, type="pearson")
  hist(sresid) 
  qqnorm(sresid); qqline(sresid, col="red")
  
  fits<-fitted(model)
  plot(sresid~fits) 
  
  boxplot(mydata$Response)
  cooksd <- cooks.distance(model) %>% as.data.frame(); outliers <- cooksd %>%  filter(. > 4/2400) 
  



